# How can I get the x11 buffer from a TK window?

Tags: opengl, tk-toolkit

In Linux Ubuntu 14. I would like display some graphic animation from a TCL/Tk widget. For the Graphic animation I will use OpenGl. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the tcl3d package by Paul Obermeier:

http://www.tcl3d.org/

Comment: Thanks Brad. I already knew about it but it is using swing. I would like to know how I do get directly the X11 buffer. if it is possible.

Comment: @Jesus: There is no such thing as a X11 "buffer". X11 has *drawables* and you can create a context on those. Furthermore Tcl3D does not use *SWI* __N__ *G* (which is a UI toolkit, note the extra N) but *SWIG* which is an tool for automatically creating cross-language API bindings. SWIG is used only at the time of building Tcl3D but never at runtime.

Comment: There are ways to capture a single window, but I can't find anything (already coded) that will use the entire x11 frame buffer.